# Two ajax functions in one javascript file

Tags: java, ajax, jsp

I have two functions that are called to do ajax requests based on the used click events. However only one of the following ajax requests works. When I comment the first function then second function works, and when I comment second one, then the first one works.

```
function ajaxFunction(mid){

    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server

    // need to do AJAX GET REQUEST TO SERVLET
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "/nweWar1/moviePopUp?MovieId=" + mid, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null);
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){


            $("#myModalContent").html(ajaxRequest.responseText);
            $("#myModal").modal();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: never did ajax in java, but would it have something to do with the location of the send request?

Comment: Do you have two different functions or the same function is bound to two different events? Do you have any JS error in the dev console? or the event is simply ignored?

Comment: I found my problem. I forgot to include js file.